# Error when trying to create a release pipeline using the Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to create a release pipeline using the Azure Devops API and I've got back the following error:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "VS402936: Release pipeline with ID 467 does not exist. Specify a valid ID and try again.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi.Exceptions.ReleaseDefinitionNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.WebApi",
    "typeKey": "ReleaseDefinitionNotFoundException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

I was under the impression that sending a POST request to [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0) would actually create the release pipeline - have I misunderstood this?

My understanding of this came from this question: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/api-documentation-out-of-date/1437337 which did help me create a build pipeline

Please find the request body below - note some values will be different as I've removed personal and organisational information:

```
{
  "id": 467,
  "name": "testProject",
  "source": "restApi",
  "revision": 1,
  "description": "Built by project_setup.py",
  "createdBy": null,
  "createdOn": "2021-11-23T10:55:39.418Z",
  "modifiedBy": null,
  "modifiedOn": "2021-11-23T10:55:39.418Z",
  "isDeleted": false,
  "variables": {},
  "variableGroups": [],
  "environments": [
    {
      "id": 628,
      "name": "dev",
      "retentionPolicy": {
        "daysToKeep": 30,
        "releasesToKeep": 3,
        "retainBuild": true
      },
      "preDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": false,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "approver": {
              "displayName": null,
              "id": "aeb95c63-4fac-4948-84ce-711b0a9dda97"
            },
            "id": 628
          }
        ]
      },
      "postDeployApprovals": {
        "approvals": [
          {
            "rank": 1,
            "isAutomated": true,
            "isNotificationOn": false,
            "id": 628
          }
        ]
      },
      "deployPhases": [
        {
          "deploymentInput": {
            "parallelExecution": {
              "parallelExecutionType": "none"
            },
            "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
            "artifactsDownloadInput": {},
            "queueId": 154,
            "demands": [],
            "enableAccessToken": false,
            "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
            "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1,
            "condition": "succeeded()",
            "overrideInputs": {}
          },
          "rank": 1,
          "phaseType": "agentBasedDeployment",
          "name": "Run on agent",
          "workflowTasks": []
        }
      ],
      "environmentOptions": {
        "emailNotificationType": "OnlyOnFailure",
        "emailRecipients": "release.environment.owner;release.creator",
        "skipArtifactsDownload": false,
        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
        "enableAccessToken": false,
        "publishDeploymentStatus": false,
        "badgeEnabled": false,
        "autoLinkWorkItems": false,
        "pullRequestDeploymentEnabled": false
      },
      "demands": [],
      "conditions": [],
      "executionPolicy": {
        "concurrencyCount": 0,
        "queueDepthCount": 0
      },
      "schedules": [],
      "properties": {},
      "preDeploymentGates": {
        "id": 628,
        "gatesOptions": null,
        "gates": []
      },
      "postDeploymentGates": {
        "id": 628,
        "gatesOptions": null,
        "gates": []
      },
      "environmentTriggers": [],
      "rank": 1,
      "owner": {
        "displayName": "<myemail>",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/<mycompany>/_apis_Identities/<myid>",
        "_links": {
          "avatar": {
            "href": "https://dev.azure.com/w2globaldata/_apis/GraphProfile/MemberAvatars/<mydescriptor>"
          }
        },
        "id": "<myid>",
        "uniqueName": "<myemail>",
        "imageUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/<company>/_api/_common/identityImage?id=<myid>",
        "descriptor": "<mydescriptor>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "artifacts": [],
  "triggers": [],
  "releaseNameFormat": null,
  "tags": [],
  "properties": {},
  "projectReference": null,
  "_links": {}
}
```

If anyone could offer any help, or has any experience of this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what you want to create.... In your case, it seems like you want to update an existing release definition with id 467 that you are defined in the body:

```
{ "id": 467, }
```

If you want to create a release definition, you have to use this example: [Create release definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples). So try to remove the ID property.

If you want to create new release of an existing release definitions, use this example: [Sample Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples)

Comment: Awesome thats working - thank you so much!